# Best practices for checking code log in R for issues

Tags: r

I am using R for some regular processing and would like to, where possible, automate the process as it has to be run daily.

At the same time as making the process as automated as possible I would like to put some checks in place to ensure that the code runs correctly. Currently this is in two parts:

- I create a summary HTML document with key bits of information from the run that is emailed to the user for checking
- I `sink` the code log then at the end of the run read it back in to check for certain key words (for example: ERROR, WARNING etc)

My question is in two parts:

1. Can you give some advice on what key words I should be searching for to check for issues in the R log (outside of - ERROR, WARNING...)?
2. Are there any other best practices that could be recommended to help improve my process?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have tests in your code, such as "Does import result in a data.frame with the expected columns?", "Are column classes as expected?", etc?

Comment: Thanks, good suggestions. I don't have these, currently I just check distribution of certain variables, check for duplicates,  print an example 10 rows in dataframe etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step, I'd just search your log for the strings `"Warning:"` and `"Error:"`. Depending on your application, it could be better to actually handle the errors and warnings e.g. with `tryCatch`.

I'd also make sure that the code does what it's supposed to by writing various checks. This is easily done using the `testthat`, `assertthat`, or the `assertive` package.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, I will investigate the packages suggested